# Only hover image inside a div with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I would like to animate just an image when hovering over a card (div) and not the card itself. How would I go about doing that?

The plan is to have the image animate-bounce when hovering over the card and only the image not the card or the text inside.

Also, im using next/image for the image.

Normal CSS, I would nest the css and it would work, can that be done with TailwindCSS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this, haven't tested though, but the idea is to nest the child within the parent:

```
.parent:hover > .child {
    animation: bounce 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why not